# UISplitViewController is only supported when running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Dont mark this as a duplicate. The issue I'm facing is quite different. This issue is coming if it try to launch in iPad 5.1 simulator. I am using split view controller in my app. I'm creating instance of split view only if it is iPad. Checking this condition under `idiomPad`.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
      [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
   else
      [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

Even though the code is under idiomPad, the app is crashing after showing splash screen. It is not coming to `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions` too. The split view code is inside application `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions` methods. Splashscreen is default.png.

Dont know why it is crashing even before coming to `didfinishlaunching`.

Note: I am trying the launching in iPad. So it should work properly. This code is working in iPhone 5.1, 6.0 and iPad 6.0 simulators. Only problem with iPad 5.1 simulator.

App target : Universal
Deployment Target : 4.2

Comment: Are you sure you've instantiated the split view controller?

Comment: Yes. I tried commenting split view code and relaunched the iPad simulator. Even then the app crashes. Looks quite strange. Without split view code, how it is crashing throwing uisplitviewcontroller  error.

Comment: Could you add the crash reason and/or stacktrace?

Comment: Crash reason in console is "UISplitViewController is only supported when running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad". This is what i got.